# Spring Rest and JPA

Tags: spring, rest, jpa

Am facing a strange design issue, I am designing a online application as part of learning. It has a customer entity and an address entity. Customer has a set of addresses entity inside (one to many) and address has one reference to customer (many to one). 
Now when a customer registers, he passes his details as well as the set of addresses via json through a rest service. I need to save customer and the list of addresses using CRUD repository. For this am using save() and saveall().

But am not seeing any where how I can catch any errors from save() and saveall() so that I can return a valid message back to the customer. ?

```
class Customer {
.
.

@OneToMany
Set<Address> address

}

class Address {
..
.
@ManyToOne
Customer customer
.
.
}
```

regards 
Achuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring JPA throws unchecked exceptions which means compilers don't force you to implement catch routines but you have to catch the runtime exceptions and handle properly to display the error message to the users.
you can handle this with ExceptionResolver like this,

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class ExceptionResolver {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionResolver.class);

    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public String handleException(Exception exception) {
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        return exception.getMessage();
    }
}
```